# App Inventor - Creating a database

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have a problem with App Inventor. I need to create a database consisting of:
For any number I want to add, I want to add four variables (eg to 3 I want to assign a name, address, email, to 5 different name, different name, different address and email) I want all data to be saved regardless of how many digits will be To which to add variables. Then, in another window, you want to give the box where the number is typed, and underneath there are variables assigned to it. Yes, I have everything, but I do not save all the data except the last number with the variables (the last one overwrites the previous one). Please help

Comment: see the [TinyDB tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/stevozip/home/AI2/tinydb) by Stephen.

Comment: A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles  
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .